# Is there a book equivalent to « Good work if you can get: How to succeed in academia » but for European / UK academia?

Tags: graduate-school, career-path, academic-life, books, europe

I found Jason Brennan’s book very useful when applying to my PhD and planning long term about my academic career.
However I am doing my PhD in Europe and although I’d like to explore US academia at some point in my career, I’d bet that long term I may prefer to be somewhere in Europe.
Of course, 75% of the advice in the book applies equally in here, but there are different things (eg sorter PhD without courses or having to TA, I think tenure-track positions don’t exist, etc)

Comment: Europe has lots of variation between countries, especially in those aspects you mention (level of coursework and TA-ship during PhD, existence of tenure-tracks). On the other hand, getting informed about these particular aspects might not require a book.